# What is the fastest way to group a DateTime column by Date in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have an older sql 2005 box, and I need to do some summaries of a table with ~500m rows.

I have a datetime column in the table and I want to get just the date out of it for output and group by. I know there are a few ways to do this, but what is the absolute fastest?

Thanks

Comment: Can you at least provide sample queries of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Query the data in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: There are so many "it depends" variables here I almost feel like I should delete my answer.

Comment: Leaving spew? -1 to vague question without example and attitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suspect* the fastest would be to:

```
SELECT
  the_day = DATEADD(DAY, the_day, '19000101'), 
  the_count
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    the_day = DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', [the_datetime_column]), 
    the_count = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.the_table
  GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', [the_datetime_column])
  WHERE ...
) AS x;
```

But "fastest" is relative here, and it will depend largely on the indexes on the table, how you're filtering out rows, etc. You will want to test this against other typical date truncation methods, such as `CONVERT(CHAR(8), [the_datetime_column], 112)`.

What you could consider - depending on whether this query is more important than write performance - is adding a persisted computed column with an index, or an indexed view, that would help this aggregation for you at write time instead of query time.

Comment: The datetime field is indexed, and I am basically doing a simple select count(*), date with a group by on the date. I know I can just do a convert, or datepart to group by date (ignore the time), but I was hoping there was guidance on what was the fastest to group by. Thanks Aaron.

Comment: Ok, interesting. the datediff method was 3x faster than what I did with date part. Thanks!

Comment: Sloppy question and great answer. +1

Comment: Line 2 of your code DATEADD(DAY, '19000101', the_day) you can't add a varchar to a number. You should change it to DATEADD(DAY, the_day, '19000101'). That will cause an automatic cast from varchar to date. You could also change it to DATEADD(DAY, the_day, 0) or DATEADD(DAY, 0, the_day)

Comment: You're right, I did swap those around, but looks like the OP got the gist anyway. I'm used to using 0 rather than an explicit date, buy I'm trying to use better habits especially for public code. Anyway, corrected.

Comment: I used the `CONVERT(CHAR(8), [the_datetime_column], 112)` and it worked great...Thx

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you can get a slightly better performance this way.

```
SELECT cast(cast([actiontime]+.5 as int) as datetime) as [yourdate], count(*) as count
FROM <yourtable>
GROUP BY cast([<yourdate>]+.5 as int)
```

You can improve this once you upgrade to mssql server 2008.

```
SELECT cast([<yourdate>] as date) as [yourdate], count(*) as count
FROM <yourtable>
GROUP BY cast([<yourdate>] as date)
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it. Yes, wish I had the authority to push this to sql 2008, as the date type would be nice.